# utility program for issuing raw HTTP commands?

Tags: windows, http

Dumb question: is there a **batch-mode** utility (e.g. particular options for curl or wget) that can let me issue raw HTTP commands, and either output the raw results or pipe/redirect it as I see fit?

I know telnet theoretically works but I'm running Windows XP and both Microsoft telnet and PuTTY seem to be interactive and seem to screw things up.

---

**edit:** (clarification) I've used curl before, so am familiar w/ the idea, as well as how to send parameters via GET/POST, just not how to control the headers explicitly, and how to keep headers in the output... I can see two possible methods that would be useful to me:

1. **Raw HTTP I/O** -- I had meant literally like telnet but in batch mode (not opening up a new window or mucking with the terminal settings):

   ```
   GET http://someserver/someresource/blah.html
   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2009 21:23:40 GMT
     ...
   ```
2. **"easy" input, raw HTTP output** -- using curl in the normal methods, but being able to see the raw output verbatim:

   ```
   > curl --some-option --another-option http://someserver/someresource/blah.html
   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2009 21:23:40 GMT
     ...
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both curl and wget can do this. Please give us more details on what kind of commands you want to execute.

Random example:

```
wget --post-data="Some random data sent via POST" "http://example.com/cgi/something.php?arg=1&foo=bar" -q -O results.txt
```

Sends some data via POST, as well as some arguments via GET to a specific URL. -q means don't give me progress updates, -O specifies what file to output to. Use `-O -` if you would like to pipe the results instead of saving to a file.

Comment: Curl or wget cannot send a bunch of http headers specified in a file with the request, which is what I understood OP was after.

Answer (score 2):

Curl or wget are good options.  But if you really want to have something equivalent to telnet you should probably use [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) ([win32](http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/139)) instead of using telnet.  Netcat is designed for raw i/o telnet isn't.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Client for Mac OS X is handy, http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/

Comment: The OP said nothing about OS X.

Answer (score 1):

For "easy" input, raw HTTP output : `curl -i --raw http://google.fr`

For the other i guess that telnet is your best chance.

Answer (score 0):

telnet

http://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Telnet-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: or 'netcat' if you prefer.